# LTSPICE MOSFET based Voltage Divider SImulation and Real Circuit Results Do Not Match

Tags: mosfet, voltage-divider

I am trying to build a very low current voltage divider. I picked high load design using NMOS and PMOS in LTSPICE. In LTSPICE current in R4 is almost zero (nA) when Vin is zero, but in a real circuit i still measure 6.4uA. Can anyone, please, see an issue with this circuit?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: What's the worst case \$I_\text{DSS}\$ for \$M_1\$ and for \$M_3\$ and have you measured the current in \$R_2\$ in both pulse-cases? (I already know you measured it in \$R_4\$, so I don't need that figure if I can assume you get the same number in both cases.) I'm suspicious that your \$M_3\$ device may have a high \$I_\text{DSS}\$.

Comment: for M1 Idss = 1uA for Vgs = 0, Vds = 48V , for M3 Idss = 500nA at VDs =-25V, Current in R2 (via voltage across):Vin = 0, I(R2) ~ .24uA, Vin = 3.3V, I(R2) ~ 32uA

Comment: i will try some other parts. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for checking those details. \$M_3\$'s \$I_\text{DSS}\$ does NOT seem like a serious problem, then. It might develop a few hundred millivolts across \$R_3\$ and \$R_4\$. But that doesn't seem to explain your experience. And I figure you must have already verified that the circuit is clean and that there aren't other leakage paths, as I'm sure you are well aware that you are dealing with microamps. Perhaps bad devices. Maybe remove the BS250 from the circuit, tie its gate to its source and see what leaks when applying \$3.3\:\text{V}\$ from souce to drain? Just to be sure?

Comment: well, this is embarrassing, but this fool had PMOS connected as NMOS. Very sorry. When i fixed the connection i got a good agreement with the simulation and zero current. Now about your test suggestion. I measured about 2.8mA. Does that sound right?  Here is model data: .MODEL MOST1 PMOS(LEVEL=3 VTO=-2.3 W=7.6m L=2u KP=10.33u RD=4.014 RS=20m)
.MODEL MOST2 PMOS(VTO=2.43 W=7.6m L=2u KP=10.33u RS=20m)
.MODEL Dbody D(CJO=53.22E-12 VJ=0.5392 M=0.3583 IS=75.32E-15 N=1.016 RS=1.245
+              TT=86.56n BV=45 IBV=10u)

Comment: i did not know how to attach the data sheet from DigiKey. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Digikey only shows Diodes Inc BS250's. So, I'm assuming you are either using the TO-92 or else the SOT-23 packaged choices. Both show a threshold voltage of anywhere between \$-1\:\text{V}\$ to \$-3.5\:\text{V}\$. (See [BS250F](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/BS250F.pdf) and [BS250P](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/BS250P.pdf).) Neither sheet shows much more. I believe that if you tied the gate to the source, you shouldn't see much current. But if you tied the gate to the drain, you'd see some.

Comment: got it. Thanks. I will try a different MOSFET with a lower Vth.